# while deserialising the protobuf as per .proto value is empty string

Tags: protocol-buffers

protobuf:

message  test
{

```
      int16 a:1

message testdata{
       int16   b:1    `
       int16   c:2

repeated testdata test_data=2
}

}
```

`dt`=test()
`dt`.a=11
dt1=d.`testdata`.add()
dt1.b=2222
dt1.c=3333
send=`dt`.`SerializeToString`()

now while deserialising code as below:

```
t=test()
t.ParseFromString(send)
t1=t.testdata()
print(t1.test_data)----> empty string
print(t1.b)--> value is not printing as expected, its printing object name instead of value.

how to access the nested protobuf elements and any input or suggestions are welcome.
```

Comment: sorry while adding .proto i missed add "repeated testdata test_data=2: for nested protobuf. In my protobuf file its there.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).

Your `protobuf` file is invalid.

A working equivalent of what you've written could be:

`example.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message test {

    int32 a=1;

    message testdata {
        int32 b=1;
        int32 c=2;
    }

    repeated testdata test_data=2;
}
```

Compiled using:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/example.proto
```

Example Python code (with apologies for my poor variable naming choices):

```py
import example_pb2

from google.protobuf.message import DecodeError

# Create a test message (f)
f = example_pb2.test()
f.a = 1

# Add a repeated property of type testdata
g=f.test_data.add()
g.b=1
g.c=1

# Add a repeated property of type testdata
g=f.test_data.add()
g.b=2
g.c=2

# Add a repeated property of type testdata
g=f.test_data.add()
g.b=3
g.c=3

# Output it
print(f)

# Serialize it and output it
x=f.SerializeToString()
print(x)

# Create a new test message (h) and parse x into it
h=example_pb2.test()
h.ParseFromString(x)
print(h)

# Create incorrectly formatted message (y) as a variant of x
y=b'\x08\x01\x12\x12\x04\x08\x01\x10\x01\x12\x04\x08\x02\x10\x02\x12\x04\x08\x03\x10\x03'
j=example_pb2.test()
try:
    j.ParseFromString(y)
    print(j)
except DecodeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Yielding:

```
a: 1
test_data {
  b: 1
  c: 1
}
test_data {
  b: 2
  c: 2
}
test_data {
  b: 3
  c: 3
}

b'\x08\x01\x12\x04\x08\x01\x10\x01\x12\x04\x08\x02\x10\x02\x12\x04\x08\x03\x10\x03'
a: 1
test_data {
  b: 1
  c: 1
}
test_data {
  b: 2
  c: 2
}
test_data {
  b: 3
  c: 3
}

Error parsing message
```

Comment: yes... i have tried its working fine for above example sending and deserialising the data.
what if  what ever the data we received in the form of protobuf is not proper. how can i identify and tell them. Protobuf data incorrect.

Comment: You would only receive incorrectly formatted messages if the originator were not using a protobuf library to generate the message; it's not possible for the protobuf generated client|server to generate incorrectly formatted messages. However, if the originator were manually creating the message, it is possible. You would then e.g. catch a `DecodeError` exception on `ParseFromString`. I've updated the answer.